# How to show the entered items in a list inside text area

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make an html form which asks the user to input values in a text field and click "submit" button. After the user clicks the "submit" button, the value should be appended to a list of all previously entered values. The user should be able to select the entered item to edit or remove it. Something that should look similar to this:

[image]

I tried to use this code. The item gets added to the list but not inside a box in clickable format as I showed in the image before.

```
var button = document.getElementById("submit-button");
var text = document.getElementById("text-field");
var list=document.getElementById("list");
button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode(text.value);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

//to append the item
list.appendChild(node);}
    , false);
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the html code:

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>

  <body>    
  <form> 
      Enter URL: <br>
      <input type="text" id="text-field">
      <br> 
      <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
  <script src="myscript.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you mind to share your HTML too please?

Comment: `var listItem = '<li>' + text + '</li>';` should be `var listItem = '<li>' + text.value + '</li>';`. "text" in your code is an object representing the "text-field" element, not the actual text within the element.

Comment: Thanks. I did added .value. But after I submit the button, no list appears. The list does not exist in my page.

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your `button` element or call `event.preventDefault()` from your event listener. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/932653/215552 for more information.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan I added `event.preventDefault()`, this did not help in showing the list in the HTML page.

Comment: but in your html snippet there is no dom element with list id attribute

Comment: @marmeladze I corrected it. Now I get a list item added but fixed list not like the image I posted where list items are shown inside a box and can be clicked and highlighted once clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `select`, not `ul` tag:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("submit-button");
var text   = document.getElementById("text-field");
var select = document.getElementById("select");

button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (!text.value) {
    return false;
  }
  
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(text.value);
  var node = document.createElement("option");
  node.appendChild(textnode);

  //to append the item
  select.appendChild(node);
  text.value = '';
  
  return false;
});
```

```css
#select {
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form> 
  Enter URL: <br>
  <input type="text" id="text-field">
  <br> 
  <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
<br />
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```